Power Automate Flows Several Conditions to Check - Dynamics 365
We are building D365 CRM and Sales Systems and Our business requires a lot of customisation to Case records. Things like: if subject contains "this" set its "custom column"s value to "this"  OR if the subject contains "this" ASSIGN the case to "this" OR EVEN if a case's status set to "This" send an e-mail to "this"
Now imagine having around 20 rules like this with unique requirements for each of them. D365 generates a record creating Flow from a template. It gets triggered when an e-mail arrives, creates a case record. I'd like to add a step before the creation step and customise the relevant fields according to conditions. But since there are various scenarios I couldn't be sure what would be most practical approach to this. I'm open to new ideas like using external sources and such.
I'm merely asking for opinions.
I've tried creating a queue for each rule but turns out it creates a mailbox for every queue and the same address can only be used for 1 address.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please visit the Help center, take a Tour to see what and How to Ask. Do some research or search for related topics on SO. If you get stuck, post a Minimal, Reproducible Example of your attempt, noting input and expected output.
